# PHP DOMDocument replaceChild

Tags: php, dom, replace, children

I can't get this method to work.

I have this PHP code:

```
        $dom = new \DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML($this->_html);

        $newD = $viewElement->replaceHtml();


        $oe = $dom->getElementById("{{ALViewElement_resume}}");
        $ne = $newD->getElementById("resume");


        echo $dom->saveHTML();
        echo $dom->saveHTML($oe);
        echo $newD->saveHTML($ne);
        echo $dom->saveHtml($oe->parentNode);
        $oe->parentNode->replaceChild($ne, $oe);

        echo $dom->saveHTML($ne);
        echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

So I create a DOMDocument, and load some html. I then call `$viewElement->replaceHtml()` which is a function I have elsewhere that returns another DOMDocument Object.

Then `$oe` is the element I have originally in the passed in html and $ne is the element in the DOMDocument that was created in my replaceHtml call. I want to replace `$oe` with `$ne`.

I then have all these echos. The first one will show what `$dom` to begin with, and that's correct.

The next will show you the original element (the one I want to replace) and that's correct. Notice the id starts with {{ALViewElement_.

The next shows you the element I want to replace the original element with. Notice it's like the same thing except the id doesn't start with ALViewElement. ***And no I am not looking for answers saying I can change the id with DOMDocument very easily because that's not what I'm looking for here.***

The next call shows the parentNode of the original element. It was just an html fragment so there actually is no parentNode. This prints itself. Notice the {{ALViewElement_ id.

I then call replace child.

Then the next two echos print nothing. replaceChild didn't work and I lost everything.

Why is this not working? What am I missing?

EDIT: Forgot the HTML.

I put them in a jsFiddle so it's easy to see: https://jsfiddle.net/jDPTC/

Comment: I see alot of post with a `\\` before DOMDocument. What does that mean?

Comment: It's due to my namespace.

Comment: @user1513171 See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php - the backslash is needed to reference a class from the global namespace

Comment: Ok thanks. I assure you this is not the problem though. I can call all the other methods just fine.

Answer (score 1):

you should clone your new node first, e.g.

```
$oe->parentNode->replaceChild($ne->cloneNode(true), $oe);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.clonenode.php